# how to load all clojure namespaces from an external jar file

Tags: clojure

I'm a newbie to classloading and wish to be able to do the following:

```
(load-all "/path/to/clojure_lib.jar")
```

And it will then load all the clojure *.clj files in the jar file into my project.

How can this be done?

Comment: Use pomegranate if it's a Jar (https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate). Check out clojure.tools.namespace and juxt/jig :)

Comment: Thanks! It works great! please write up your comment and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load Clojure projects from jars in runtime, use *pomegranate* https://github.com/cemerick/pomegranate. Notice that it also works when the .clj files are not included (e. g. `:omit-source` in project.clj is true).

Also check out `clojure.tools.namespace` and `juxt/jig`.